SSL error: The certificate authority is not trusted
While rendering a web view in react native using react-native-webview, I got an error,
SSL error: The certificate authority is not trusted.

I have also put false to newArchEnabled just to get this react-native-webview get working.
React Native Version: 0.76.1
react-native-webview version: 13.6.3
Tried everything given

Add the root certificate to your app using a package like react-native-ssl-pinning. If you're using a self-signed certificate, you need to explicitly pin it. Also, check if the server's certificate chain is complete.Sometimes intermediate certificates are missing, causing trust issues.
